# JPA Entity class Relationship

Tags: hibernate, jpa, entity, jpa-2.0

I have the following Entity class structure

**Product class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PRODUCTS")
public class Product implements Serializable{

@Id
private productSlNo;
@Column(name = "PRODUCT_ID")
private String productNo;
```

**ProductDetail class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PRODUCTDETAILS")
public class ProductDetail extends Product implements Serializable {

@Column(name = "PRODUCT_DESC")
private String productDesc;
```

As I already have `productNo` in Product class I did not declare it in `ProductDetail` class.

I would like to know how can I have the mandatory `@Id` annotation in `ProductDetail` class as the unique key is defined in `Product` class. Otherwise this will result in **The entity has no primary key attribute defined** error.
`productNo` is a unique key for ProductDetail Entity

How can I solve this? Any help is highly appreciable.

**Update 1**

**ProductDetail class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PRODUCTDETAILS")
public class ProductDetail implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column(name = "PRODUCT_ID")
private String productNo;

@Column(name = "PRODUCT_DESC")
private String productDesc;
```

**Product class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PRODUCTS")
public class Product implements Serializable{

@Id
private productSlNo;

@Id
@Column(name = "PRODUCT_ID")
@OneToOne 
@MapsId     
private String productNo;

ProductDetail productDetail;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can a Product exist without a ProductDetail?  The first try would work - the two classes would share the same Product table, with ProductDetails using "PRODUCTDETAILS" as a secondary table.  This would allow you to have Products and ProductDetails, but a Product cannot be turned into a ProductDetail.  The second update means that a Product must have a ProductDetail (your annotation is on a String, when I assume you meant for it to be on the productDetail attribute instead) since the defined ProductDetail maps and basically defines the Product's ID.  If a Product can exist without a detail, you might want to switch this around, so that Product has a bidirectional 1:1 with ProductDetail with the foriegn key in ProductDetail:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PRODUCTDETAILS")
public class ProductDetail implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="PRODUCT_ID")
    private Product product;

    @Column(name = "PRODUCT_DESC")
    private String productDesc;
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PRODUCTS")
public class Product implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "PRODUCT_ID")
    private productSlNo;

    @OneToOne(mappedby="product")   
    ProductDetail productDetail;
```

This will cause ProductDetail to pull the "PRODUCT_ID" value as defined from the referenced Product.

Comment: Chris Product cannot exist without being in ProductDetail. Basically ProductDetail is nothing but a look up table. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The default strategy of entity inheritance is to store every field of every entity in the same table. So your mapping doesn't make sense, since you speciy a different table on the sub-entity.

First choose the inheritanc strategy you want to use, and then annotate your classes accordingly. The 3 inheritance strategies are defined and explained in [the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e6906).

That said, if the goal is to have a product and additional detailed information information about this product, you shouldn't use inheritance, but have a OneToOne association instead.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You mean to say that my mapping tables are different, there is no point in avoiding `productNo` in `ProductDetail ` Entity?

Comment: It is basically a lookup information I have in `PRODUCTDETAILS` table where I look for the details of a given `productNo`

Comment: To your first question, no, that's not what I said. I said that since your (default) inheritance strategy is SINGLE_TABLE, specifying a table for the sub-entity dosn't make any sense. So you should choose the inheritance strategy that you desire, and fix the mapping, based on the documentation. To your second comment, since you use inheritance, you define a is-a association. What you want is a has-a association: a product has details. So you shouldn't use inheritance but composition: a OneToOne association.

Comment: I have modified my Entity classes and included as Update 1 in my question. As I am using a shared primary key, is my approach correct? Thanks